# How do I stop this simple actionscript?

Tags: flash, function, actionscript

I'm making a short little interactive E-card for school. It takes you through the scenes of "a Christmas story." Right now I'm working on the part where Ralphie beats up Farkus.

I want it so you can use the left and right arrow keys to throw punches, but if you choose to end the scene, you can simply click a button and finish Farkus off.

So I have this code here, which simply takes you to certain frames using the arrow keys.

The problem is, is when I click the button, I want all of that code to disappear. Right now it doesn't. If I hit one of the arrow keys after I click the button, the code still brings me to the beginning of the scene.

```
stop();

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, punchfarkusleft);

function punchfarkusleft(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        this.gotoAndPlay(1980);
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, punchfarkusright);

function punchfarkusright(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        this.gotoAndPlay(1995);

    }
}
```

I'm totally new to actionscript. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
stop();

function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    // removing the listener will stop the handler being executed on 
    // subsequent keyUp events
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

    // We can handle any number of keys in the handler now
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        this.gotoAndPlay(1995);
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        this.gotoAndPlay(1980);
    {
}

// Only add one event listener for keyUp event
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately the code didn't work, but I figured out how to stop the action from playing.

Comment: My mistake; didn't look at the code properly before firing off an answer ;). See updated answer with some comments which will hopefully be useful to you.